# I'm not able to change my website to reserved mode in Azure

Tags: azure, web, instance, reserved

I'm trying to change my websites to the reserved mode but I can't... No matter the instance size I choose.

Comment: Were you able to change to reserved mode once more capacity was available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Additional Capacity has recently been added:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/07/17/additional-reserve-instance-capacity-for-windows-azure-web-sites-preview.aspx

They are in the process of adding capacity all the time. I have run into his in the past as well. I know this is not the answer you want to hear, but try again every couple days and more instances will be available.

Keep in mind this is preview technology. Microsoft is in the process of assessing both usage and demand